# A cookie with both PHP and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, cookies

Can I edit a cookie created by JavaScript with PHP and vice versa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, a cookie is a cookie.

**setcookie.html:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.cookie = 'foo=bar';
</script>
<a href="readcookie.php">Did it work?</a>
```

**readcookie.php:**

```
<?PHP 
echo 'This should say "bar": ' . $_COOKIE['foo'];
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can.  However, be aware that the cookie must allow for JavaScript to edit it.  There is a flag `HttpOnly` that can be added to an HTTP cookie header which disallows editing of cookies by browser scripting languages like JavaScript in supported browsers.  You can see it in the function signature:

```
bool setcookie ( string $name [, string $value [, int $expire = 0 [, string $path [, string $domain [, bool $secure = false [, bool $httponly = false ]]]]]] )
```

If it is set to `true` (the default is `false`) then the cookie cannot be edited using JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Cookies are accessible only by the same origin. Some cookies have rules set, like `only accessible by https` or `only accessible by *.images.google.com`.  It doesn't matter if the cookie is set via JS or PHP so long as it is saved by the browser using the same origin parameters.

Access (`read` OR `write`) of the cookie is totally up to the browser, though the behavior is specified by [RFC 2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109).

Answer (score -1):

Only web browser stores your cookies. It sends them to script on each request. Script sends them back with a reply.